# Maven is not copying *.xml files in src/test/java to target/test-classes by default

Tags: java, maven, testing, resources, classpath

I have been out of programming for awhile and I'm getting back into it, and I have come across a very peculiar problem. In the past whenever I compiled the test code from within Maven, it would copy over all of my *.xml resource files contained within the test source tree into `target/test-classes`. But last night, on my current project, it not longer did this - which is not what I expected. Whenever I ran my tests through Maven or Intellij IDEA, the tests would fail because it could not find any *.xml files in the classpath - they never got copied over.

I have older projects on my computer using exactly the same .pom file and project structure, and the *.xml files copy over fine.

To solve this problem, I included the following XML to my Maven POM:

```xml
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/*.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
```

While this solves the problem, I am still curious why I had to go out of my way to tell Maven to copy *.xml files from my test source tree to my target/test-classes directory manually. Like I said, every other older project in the last 2 years is copying the *.xml files over without me specifying `testResources`.

What could be causing this behaviour?

Comment: Is there possbily a difference with your older projects? Perhaps a different parent pom, or a different version of a plugin? In any case your usage is non-standard, the xml files should go in `src/test/resources` as Qwerky rightly says. From a maintenance perspective, I would consider moving them and fixing whatever issues it raises in the short term.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The poms and plugin versions are exactly the same. In fact, this new project is a direct fork of an earlier project, so it makes even less sense why it would suddenly stop working :/ As for being "standard", I am not concerned about it. This project has a extremely complex domain model, and it's not possible to neatly create test data in src/test/resources that is shared acrossed all of the test classes. There literally thousands of xml files that are all different, and must be this way. To mirror it in resources would be a massive maintenance pain. In this case, it is right

Comment: @egarvi +1 Your XML blurb provided a workaround for my similar situation.

Answer (score 7):

You should put resource files in `src/test/resources` not `src/test/java`, which is for java source files.

Comment: I think in this case, when it comes to dbunit test data, I really want them paired with the java class for convenience sake. I accept your explaination, but it I am still rather stumped why it copies them over for some projects, but not my current one :( The inconsistency is bugging me :)

Comment: I'd still like to understand why this works for a large variety of projects but not this time. Is there some default in Maven that causes the inclusion of .xml files by default, but only during certain circumstances? Could it be that, for the first time, I stumbled on the instance where the files weren't copied any longer? I guess my question is more to understand why it stopped working, as I already have a work-around to the problem. I won't put them in `src/test/resources` because the mirrored package structure will be bad for the project, so I have to keep these xml files in `src/test/java`

Comment: I disagree with Qwerky's comment: it is a valid pattern to place resources with classes. This appears to be a bug in Intellij.

Comment: For some reason having spring context xml files alongside my test classes just stopped working. Moving them to src/test/resources got everything going again. It is the 'best practice' way to do it with maven and it's not really such a big deal to move them at the end of the day. Sure both approaches are valid - just decide whether you want it to 'just work' or if you want to add a workaround to your pom as per the OP.

Comment: I still have the same problem in maven 3 and Eclipse. Really a boomer.

Answer (score 1):

To control which files are (also) copied take a look at the [Resource Plugin Documentation](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html)